# Android, can't get the proguard values right

Tags: java, android

I have an Android app which works in debug and I'm trying to get it going in release using proguard.

In the app I've got

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}
```

with minifyEnable set to false, it works - but that means I'm not using proguard. The errors are:

```
com.jjoe64.graphview.helper.GraphViewXML: can't find referenced class com.jjoe64.graphview.R$styleable  
com.jjoe64.graphview.helper.GraphViewXML: can't find referenced class com.jjoe64.graphview.R    
ioio.lib.android.accessory.Adapter: can't find referenced class com.android.future.usb.UsbManager   
ioio.lib.android.accessory.Adapter$LegacyUsbManager: can't find referenced class com.android.future.usb.UsbAccessory    
ioio.lib.android.accessory.Adapter$LegacyUsbManager: can't find referenced class com.android.future.usb.UsbManager  
ioio.lib.android.accessory.Adapter$LegacyUsbManager: can't find referenced class com.android.future.usb.UsbAccessory    
ioio.lib.android.accessory.Adapter$LegacyUsbManager: can't find referenced class com.android.future.usb.UsbManager  
ioio.lib.android.accessory.Adapter$LegacyUsbManager: can't find referenced class com.android.future.usb.UsbAccessory    
ioio.lib.android.accessory.Adapter$LegacyUsbManager: can't find referenced class com.android.future.usb.UsbManager  
there were 24 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.   
Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

The proguard rules are (the additional lines)

```
#-dontwarn com.jjoe64.graphview.*
#-dontwarn ioio.lib.android.accessory.*
#-keep class com.jjoe64.graphview.** { *; }
#-keep class com.android.future.usb.** { *; }
#-keep class ioio.android.accessory.** { *; }
```

If I uncomment the 2 dontwarn lines, it will compile but not run. The jjoe64 graphing routines will run properly but not the ioio part. I know this because I can import previous runs done in the debug mode and display the graphs. This means that I can get away with dontwarn for jjoe64.

Still I tried my best to keep class for the jjoe64 just to try to get the syntax correct. I've searched what I can find and nothing seems to compile correctly. So even though I don't really need to do so, I'd like figure out first what I need to do with keep class for jjoe64 in order to make it compile. Then hopefully I will be able to make progress in the ioio case.

Edit

I want to add a fake routine which I added to try to force proguard to keep a single ioio class. I thought perhaps I could lower the number of warning by at least 1. The result was - no change whatsoever. (Then I commented out the routine since it didn't help.)

```
/*  boolean setupImports() {
    UsbManager mMan = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
    if(mMan == null) return false;
    return true;
}*/
```

Comment: uncomment last three lines of your proguard rules.

Comment: That is what I've been doing but it doesn't work, i.e. the error message remain and don't change.

Answer (score 0):

```
Add following lines to proguard rules and check the build output. 'printseeds' will list all the classes which are kept, this is to confirm if app is including intended classes.
-keepnames class com.jjoe64.graphview.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.android.future.usb.** { *; }
-keepnames class ioio.android.accessory.** { *; }
-printseeds
```

Comment: First of all Ranjan, thanks for the help. Unfortunately nothing changed. I don't understand this since the dontwarn has a decisive effect. I didn't see any printed seeds anywhere. Where should they appear? Look at the edited part of my post. I added a fake routine which I called in the hopes that it would have an effect. I expected that proguard would see that I was actively calling 1 of the routines so that would remain. It had no effect so I commented out the routine.

Comment: From what you say, apparently I am asking to keep the wrong classes. On the other hand the dontwarn shows which class I don't want warning on. The dontwarn has a decisive effect so that means the list is correct(???) printseeds shows nothing which I can see, so I remain totally confused.

Comment: I changed proguard-android-optimize.txt to proguard-android.txt in the hopes that maybe the optimize part is too aggressive. Result: no change.

Comment: I was pointed out that I was missing "lib" in keepnames class ioio.lib.android.accessory.** { *; }. Fixing the typo doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

After reading much documentation on proguard, I still couldn't find an answer which worked. From time to time there are updates to Android Studio, which I always install when they are available.

The latest update is 3.4. I expected small changes but nothing which would solve my problem with proguard. As a matter of course, I tried generating a signed apk. To my total amazement, it completed with no errors. I wasn't at home but was using my laptop. I didn't know if the magic would extend to my main computer or not.

It is really great that the latest upgrade totally fixed the problem. My proguard-rules.pro was the default file, with all of my failed attempts commented out. The problem was simply gone, and it worked "out of the box". So from my point of view, the latest upgrade 3.4, is a major upgrade which should not be missed.

Thanks to the Android studio developers.

Edit: It wasn't quite as good as it looked at first site. Still the most important point was the previous version listed warnings which had to be fixed and no matter what I did, they were never fixed.

The new version gives no errors which must be fixed, so that I can actually check something. This in itself is a huge advantage.

I found that proguard was too ambitious in eliminating classes. It reduced the apk to a size of 859.7 kB, but the application was missing classes it needed.
First I tried

```
-keep class ** {*;}
```

This got my program going but the size of the apk jumped to 1.4 mB. Finally I found

```
-keep class ioio.lib.android.** { *; }
```

kept the classes I needed and made the apk size 900.6 kB